# Porque la promesa siempre se ejecuta aunque falle. [JQuery]

Tags: jquery, promesas

Hola a todos agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Estoy aprendiendo un poco como van lo de las promesas en JQuery, asi que me puse a hacer unas pruebas. tengo el siguiente código de prueba pero veo que aunque falle una de las promesas siempre se ejecuta con normalidad.

Tengo un modal de que tiene 3 estados, al realizarse correctamente se cambia el icono de cada estado a un check en caso contrario una X, ejecuta la promesa desde el momento que le doy click al boton para abrir el modal

con estas opciones
1- primer paso
2- segundo paso
3- tercer paso

```
  $("#modalPromise").on('click',function ()
    {
       $("#modelId").modal('toggle');

        $.when(f1(), f2(), f3())
            .fail(() => {
                console.log('He fallado')
            }).then(() => {
            swal('He finalizado');
        });
    });
```

Ahora tengo estas 3 funciones simulando un tiempo para cada una, pero la funcion 2 tiene un reject el cual al fallar le pone una x al paso 2, pero aun fallando le pone un check al paso 3 (cosa que si falla la f2 ya no se deberia ejecutar la f3)

```
  function f1()
    {
        const obj=$.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $("#s1").html('<i class="fa fa-check" style="color: green"></i>')
            obj.resolve();
        },2000);
        return obj.promise(1);
    }

    function f2()
    {
        let val=0;
        const obj=$.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            if (val === 1) {
                $("#s2").html('<i class="fa fa-check" style="color: green"></i>')
                obj.resolve();
            } else {
                let respuesta='Fallé';
                $("#s2").html('<i class="fa fa-times" style="color: red"></i>')
                obj.reject(Error(respuesta));
            }
        },4000);
        return obj.promise();
    }

    function f3()
    {
        const obj=$.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $("#s3").html('<i class="fa fa-check" style="color: green"></i>')
            obj.resolve(1);
        },6000);
        return obj.promise();
    }
```

Que error estoy cometiendo u obviando. he intentado varias cosas pero nada.

Comment: no puedes cortocircuitar un grupo de promesas simplemente por el orden en que las declares. La tercera promesa puede resolverse antes de que la segunda falle. Podrías investigar el uso de Promise.some  y Promise.race a ver si te sirve una opción no determinística. `$.when` no es una implementación Promise/A+, yo no le pondría más fichas a ese camino

Comment: @ffflabs Muchas gracias investigare un poco sobre lo que me has comentado